# proper way to handle null api response value to with or without nullable model

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to handle a value from API response if the value is null, for example

```
"data": {
    "email": null,
    "username": "Janet",
},
```

from this response i want to add it to my user model

```
class UserModel {
  final String email;
  final String username;

  UserModel({required this.email, required this.username});
}
```

but what if the email value is null? should i just use this logic ?

```
 UserModel(email: data['email'] ?? '', 
              username: data['username'] ?? '',
       ),
```

and how if i make the model nullable like this

```
class UserModel {
      String? email;
      String? username;
    
      UserModel({this.email, this.username});
    }
```

what is the best approach for this? im confuse if i should use nullable model or required model and to handle if the value is null. i want the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it depends on your needs. but whether `nullable` or not, try to make your class `immutable` by defining the variable with `final`

---

- case 1: set default value in the constructor

```
class UserModel {
  final String email;
  final String username;

 const UserModel({this.email= "", this.username=""});
}
```

I would use this approach. because it really useful when we want to use it on the UI. As we know, some widget are required `non-null` value. for example

```
final user = UserModel();

// widget
Text(user.email); // its simple, because email is non-null
```

but with this case, when we set `email=null` it will set to be empty string. for example. if you want to use `toJson()` method, it will set the empty string to the `email` and `username`. see case 2 =>

- case 2: your database required `null`  as a value.

in some cases, in the `backend` use a `null` checker for some logic.

that's why, in then dart model , we have to use a `nullable` value. so we can sent `null` value to the server.

```
class UserModel {
 final String? email;
 final String? username;

  const UserModel({this.email, this.username});
}
```

now we can set `email =null`.

but in other side, when we use it to `non-null` widget property, we need to set default value.

```
final user = UserModel();

// 
Text(user.email ?? "");
```